# Pagination issue in a category page [WordPress]

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I wanted to show one category posts from all custom post types, which my code does very well but pagination just stopped working.
here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-9 exerpts-wrap">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        query_posts(array(
            'post_type' => array('post', 'resources', 'products'),
            'category__in' => array(3)
        ));

        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="blog-sec">

                    <?php get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); ?>

                </div> <!-- blog-sec ends here -->

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div> <!-- col-sm-6 ends here -->

        <?php pagination_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>
    </div> <!-- exerpts-wrap fix ends here -->
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please tell what is "pagination_numeric_posts_nav", it does not seem to be a WordPress core funciton.

Comment: "pagination_numeric_posts_nav" is the custom function i created for pagination which works totally fine through out the website except on this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I been looking for a solution of this issue since long time and now i got a solution for this.
I am answering my own question so it helps someone else who are facing same issue.

All i did to fix this issue is to install a plugin called "Cat Post Type" and nothing else, everything works great now.

I knew my code wasn't wrong. Plugin doesn't add anything visually in admin section, it just add some code which fixes this issue.

Goodluck!